# Xamarin android app has stopped / SIGSEGV fatal error

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, segmentation-fault

I have another problem with Xamarin. After asking my previous problem, I managed to get it running without eny errors/warnings, but the problem is, that when I run it it shows message "MyApp.Android has stopped". I tried to run it on my tablet Samsung SM-T580. After trying some things (one of them to untick "Fast Deployment") I've got errors in the output:

```css
03-13 14:24:46.477 E/mono-rt (15974): No native Android stacktrace (see debuggerd output).

03-13 14:24:46.477 E/mono-rt (15974): =================================================================
03-13 14:24:46.477 E/mono-rt (15974): Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
03-13 14:24:46.477 E/mono-rt (15974): a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
03-13 14:24:46.477 E/mono-rt (15974): used by your application.
03-13 14:24:46.477 E/mono-rt (15974): =================================================================

03-13 14:24:46.478 F/libc    (15974): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xff335fd8 in tid 15974 (mpanyname.Notes), pid 15974 (mpanyname.Notes)
```

There's the project if that helps: https://github.com/EdgarKa/MasterDetailPage.git. Please help me to solve that problem.

Comment: From shared project,after testing it, there lose some files.Maybe this project when uploading has some files not success .

Comment: After resintalling NuGet Packages ,this project work well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in order

1 - Delete the App from your device

2 - Delete the bin and obj folders found in the MyApp.Android folder

3 - Restore your NuGet packages

4 - Close and re-open Visual Studio

5 - Perform a Solution Rebuild

6 - Deploy to device using play button

I've resolved SIGSEGV issues with this process before.

Comment: Didn't work for me. "obj" now is missing. "bin" restores everytime I delete every package to reinstall so I kept deleting it.

Comment: Try flipping the order of steps 2 and 3. 

Those folders missing is the goal. When you build the project, it should generate them again

Comment: That didn't help either :/